# mark points on shapefile using python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to mark specific lat long coordinates on a shapefile using python. I am trying to use the plot function from matplotlib to do it. In the examples that have been provided, a basemap object needs to be created first. How can i know the parameters for creating the basemap object for reading my shapefile? Also, is this the right approach to mark lat long coordinates on a map.